# scikit learn, find new music for user

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I want to write a program which will find new music for user, having only music from user's computer.

For each artist on user's computer I will create new list with words from his songs. (deleting stop-words of course )

For example: {'Placebo': {'secret': 11, 'unicorn': 8, 'helmet': 6}} and other words here

Then I want to use DictVectorizer to have my list transform into Numpy arrays or scipy.sparse matrices for use with scikit-learn estimators.

For example above it will be -  array([[ 11.,  8.,  6.])

So, for each artist on user's computer I have list.

Additionally, I have database with 1000 artists, for each of them I have this type of list too.

And now I don't know what is the best way to find artists which are somehow similar to these which user has.

Maybe there is some built-in function in scikit-learn?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in recommender system in scikit-learn. You could use a nearest neighbors classifier, though.
Have a look at [graphlab.create recommender systems.](https://dato.com/products/create/docs/graphlab.toolkits.recommender.html)